# How to enable atom.io to read STDIN?

Tags: stdin, atom-editor

Is there an easy way to pipe content to the editor atom?

For example:

```
echo "Content." | atom
```

Unfortunately atom does not get the content. The current version of gedit has the parameter `-` to enable reading of STDIN:

```
echo "Content." | gedit -
```

I could not find a similar option in the atom-help (`atom -h`)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for asking about this! I just now bumped into the same issue.

> Is there an easy way to pipe content to the editor atom?

The current `atom` command-line interface (CLI) will not open content piped to its standard input (`stdin`).

There's a [Pull Request](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/11184) open to add this functionality. The proposed solution writes contents from `stdin` to a file in `/tmp`, then opens that file in Atom.

For now, if you're open to hacking the `atom` CLI, you could manually apply [the changes proposed there](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/11184/files).