# How to open standard input content coming from shell execution

Tags: atom-editor

I want atom to open what a command outputs. For example in this case I want atom to be opened with an "hello" in it:

```
atom <(echo "hello")
```

but what I get is something like the following:

```
��'CmnD Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others. License & terms of use: http://www.unicode.org/copyright.html ���s�@t��t�К�0������� �� P�) ��< p�O ��b 0�u ���  �� ��� ��� `�� ��� 0�� �
!�� !��3!�F!`�Y!��l!��!��!���!���!@��!���!`��!��"�
```

Comment: FWIW I can reproduce similar behaviour with Atom 1.36.1 on Ubuntu 18.04. It might be a bug? Or it might be a quirk of how Bash does process substitution with anonymous pipes, or how Linux allocates fd's to different processes.

Comment: Related: [How to enable atom.io to read STDIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33237732/4518341)